# How to remove environment variable

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I am use Windows 10 pro. I try to run other Tomcat instance, but I cannot control config (`%CATALINA_HOME%`).

This is `systempropertiesadvanced` (hasn't `CATALINA_HOME` variable):
[image]

I try to echo by cmd (Administrator role)
[image]

I try to echo by cmd: (no return result)
[image]

Because I want run Tomcat correctly (other Tomcat instance), I must remove variable `CATALINA_HOME`, please help me!

Comment: If you've cleared to variable yourself then you might want to try rebooting (not shutdown) your computer and see if it gets cleared then.

Comment: Thank you, yesterday, I did the same your advice, It works. But today, nothing change.

Comment: Tomcat may be running as a service (on startup), using a batch file which sets `%CATALINA_HOME%`

Comment: Thank you. inside file \bin\startup.bat, I add this line:
`set "CATALINA_HOME=C:\data\dcv\liferay\for deploy\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62"`, it works.

Comment: @dovy Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: This is merely a trick, It doesn't resolve the above question.

Answer (score 2):

To clear an environment variable using Setx.exe at a command prompt:

Click Start, point to Programs, and then click Command Prompt.
If you want to clear a user environment variable, type the following line

```
setx <variable> ""
```

where  is the user environment variable.
If you want to clear a system environment variable, type the following line

```
setx <variable> "" -m
```

where  is the system environment variable.
Close the command prompt.
When you use Setx.exe to clear an environment variable value, the environment variable name is not affected.